# ASP.NET - How to check if one or more field values have been changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form where I register a new employee. There're 3 parts in the form: Personal info, Address info, Special Status. But there's only one button for the whole form. When I submit the form all the information is updated to the database. So three Update statements are executed against the database. The methods are UpdatePersonalInfo, UpdateAddressInfo and UpdateSpStatus. Is there a way to check if there's been a change in any field in the certain part and run update method only if it's true. So something like this:

```
if (There's been any change to the personal data of the employee)
{
  UpdatePersonalInfo;
}
if (There's been any change to the address information of the employee)
{
  UpdateAddressInfo;
}
```

Sure I know, I can save all the previous values in a session object in PageLoad and then compare them one by one before running the method. But I thought maybe there's a magic way of doing this more easily.

Comment: Are your controls just sitting on the pages, or contained in a `FormView` or anything?

Comment: Not in a FormView but inside UpDatePanels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that this is a better solution than any of the alternatives you already mentioned, but you could create a default handler to attach to the `TextChanged`, `SelectedIndexChanged`, etc events of your controls to keep track of which ones have changed.

```
List ChangedControls = new List(Of, String);
private void ChangedValue(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    WebControl cntrl = (WebControl) sender;
    ChangedControls.Add(cntrl.ID);
}
```

Then on your button click scour the `ChangedControls` list for the relevant controls.